# Consume webservice in Ruby on Rails, how to change XML tags and authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, soap, savon

I need to consume a webservice in Ruby on Rails with authentication. Successful communication is:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:pag="https://pagosinteligentes.com/">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <pag:Autenticacion>
             <!--Optional:-->
         <pag:User>aUser</pag:User>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <pag:Password>aPassword</pag:Password>
      </pag:Autenticacion>
     </soapenv:Header>
      <soapenv:Body>
         <pag:UserCheck>
            <!--Optional:-->
             <pag:account>anAccount</pag:account>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <pag:user>aUser</pag:user>
          </pag:UserCheck>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

It has a header for authentication (Autenticacion, in spanish) and a body with account and user.
I have:

```
  WSDL_URL = 'https://dev.pagosinteligentes.com/webservices/AMS/MovementsCardSWV1.asmx?WSDL'

realm = Base64.strict_encode64("aUser:aPassword")
client = Savon.client(wsdl: WSDL_URL,
                          soap_header: { 'Autenticacion:' => "Basic #{realm}"},
                          log: true, # set true to switch on logging
                          log_level: :debug,
                          pretty_print_xml: true)

    response = client.call(:user_check, message: {"account" => "anAccount", "user" => "aUser"})

    print response
```

My output is:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="https://pagosinteligentes.com/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <Autenticacion:>Basic V1NQcnVlYmE6MTIzNDU2</Autenticacion:>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <tns:UserCheck>
      <tns:account>anAccount</tns:account>
      <tns:user>aUser</tns:user>
    </tns:UserCheck>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

How can I change the `<env:` tags for `<soapenv:` and the `<tns:` for `<pag:`?

Even if a do change the tags still the authentication is not working properly as this code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pag="https://pagosinteligentes.com/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <Autenticacion:>Basic V1NQcnVlYmE6MTIzNDU2</Autenticacion:>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pag:UserCheck>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <pag:account>anAccount</pag:account>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <pag:user>aUser</pag:user>
      </pag:UserCheck>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

gives bad Request in SoapUI.
What is the difference between those tags?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change the tags. They just refer to the namespaces you have defined. You can choose those freely.

I think the problem in your case is that 'Autenticacion' lacks a namespace qualifier. In which namespace is the tag 'Autenticacion' defined? You need to include it! My wild guess is it might be defined in https://pagosinteligentes.com/. **IF** that is correct then you should write

```
<pag:Autenticacion>xxx</pag:Autenticacion>
```

The best way to find out is to create a valid request using SoapUI. If that was successful then you can build your Savon call accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Indeed the tags don't matter. The solution was to remove the token, and instead build the header like this:                               soap_header: { 'pag:Autenticacion' => { 'pag:User' => "aUser",  'pag:Password' => "aPass"} }, and offcourse try with SoapUI